# Is it Possible Have AddForce Method Affect Only The Object i am calling it from in unity 3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I use the `AddForce()` Method it affects all the Game Objects in the direction of  force vector i have specified which is kinda how physics works in real life , but i do not want that for my game , i want it to have an effect only on the object i am calling it from (ex . `ExampleGameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce();`

I want it to have an effect on the "ExampleGameObject" Only
I hope my question is clear , thanks in advance.

Comment: [`someObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce();`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html)

Comment: @Draco18s i know my code was not very accurate but it shows my point , thanks for pointing out this to me (fixed)

Comment: Draco18s posted a link ... `Rigidbody.AddForce` only affects the according rigidBody instance -> the according GameObject. I don't understand your question / What makes you think other objects are affected by it as well? (Except by the consequences of the according object colliding with them ofcourse)

Comment: @Draco18s and that's actually my problem , i do not want AddForce Method to have effect on another objects by any means even if it is colliding with them.

Comment: That's what layers are for.

Answer (score 0):

```
yourObject.GetComponent<RigidBody>().AddForce(yourForce);
```

If "yourObject" has children, those children will move together with "yourObject". If that's the case you shouldn't use "yourObject" as a parent, or if it's really necessary you could do something similar to this:

```
GameObject[] yourChildren;  
Transform[] yourChildrenPos;  
yourChildren = yourObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>().gameObject; //There is for sure a much better syntax for it, but i forgot it.  
yourChildrenPos = yourObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();

for (int i = 0; i > yourChildren.Length; i ++)
{
     yourChildren[i].transform.position = yourChildrenPos[i].position;
}
```

You just have to assign yourChildrenPos every time before you will move yourObject, and go trough that for loop every time after you moved yourObject. You can easily create a method for that. That wont be very effective and will cost a lot of processing power in a large project, but if the project isn't that big, this should do the job. I hope I helped.